# What happens to ACTIVITY threads if SCREEN OFF and disconnected from charger?

Tags: android, session, android-activity, screen, thread-sleep

I have an application which works on a user's session which is maintained between the server and the device. I using a ping technique to keep the session alive between the device and server by pinging the server every 1 min if the user is logged in. This is done using a background thread.

1. Sometimes when I turn OFF the screen and disconnect the device from its power source the background thread gets killed.
2. Sometimes the thread is active but my WiFi antennae gets turned OFF and my ping fails.

Is my approach correct? Is there a better way of doing this?

My requirement: I need to ping my server every minute to keep the session alive for various reasons and I should do this only if the user is logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to check your wi-fi connection

```
private boolean checkInternetConnection()
{
    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService (Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    return conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

if checkInternetConnection() == false you can turn on wi-fi using this in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
```

and this in your code

```
WifiManager wifiManager;
wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
   wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
}else{
   wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
}
```

I hope this help you, though this is not an exact answer to your question.

Comment: Great. Thank you George. But is it recommended for an app to connect to the WIFI without the user's knowledge? How to handle if the user is not in range of any WIFI? Should the app go for the cellular DATA? Can I handle cellular data like we do for WIFI?

Comment: When user installs your app, he read all uses-permission, that why you can connect to the WIFI without the user's knowledge. Sorry, but I'm sorry, but I have not tried to answer this questions, because there was no need

Comment: Oh thats fine. I meant user's knowledge in the sense when the screen is OFF and when the WIFI is supposed to be OFF then you kick the WIFIMANAGER to enable the WIFI antennae and reconnect to the network. Which is not expected by the user. Is it ok? or it is a bad away of doing things?  Just want to clarify on that

Comment: I don't see any problem, when user install your .apk, he knows what permissions he gives this .apk ))

Answer (score 0):

Use `Log.d` to write messages to the `Logcat` when an `Activity` life cycle event occurs, such as `onPause`, `onStop`, `onDestroy`, `onCreate`, `onStart` and `onResume`.  Also creating a `BroadcastReceiver` to log broadcast events is most helpful.